# Realloc and memmove

Tags: c

I currently have an array of struct pair. In order to insert a new element, I realloc to array to arraySize+1, and then memmove from insertIndex, arraySize-insertIndex, to the destination arr+insertIndex+1. Is there anything wrong about this logic? I'm receiving `Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation` and I suspect it's because there's something incorrect about this implementation...

The code is here:

```
arraySize++;
arr = realloc(arr,arraySize*sizeof(pair));               

...
/* Calculate insertIndex */
...                                                                 
if (insertIndex+1 < numPairs) {                                         
      memmove(arr+insertIndex+1,arr+insertIndex,arraySize-insertIndex-1);   
}
```

Comment: Size must be one that is multiplied by the `sizeof(pair)`

Comment: from the `realloc()` man page: "The function may move the memory block to a new location (whose address is returned by the function)."

Comment: Or it might return 0 on failure...

Comment: Would have expected code like `memmove(arr+insertIndex+1, arr+insertIndex, (arraySize-insertIndex-1)*sizeof(pair));`

Comment: But that's not the problem. The problem is that realloc may return NULL.

Comment: How was `arr` initialised before you first called `realloc`?

Comment: @chux that fixed my problem. thank you. It seems that there is also an issue with the use of realloc?

Comment: @simonc it was initialized to NULL.

Comment: Posting more of the code would make for less guessing.  Checking the return value of `realloc()` makes for good error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `realloc` may return 0 on failure, in which case the old pointer is still valid.
   (You need not concern yourself with the possibility that it might also return 0 if no space is requested, as you request some.)
2. You need to multiply the number of elements `memmove` shall move with the element's size.

As an aside, prefer `sizeof *pointer` to `sizeof(elementtype)`, that's less error-prone.

As a second aside, making the call unconditionally would slightly simplify your code (always great) and might not be any more expensive over multiple uses (measure), it might even be more performant.